# Pulse sensor coding for Netduino Plus 2 gone wrong

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microcontroller, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I'm currently doing a project on Netduino Plus 2 using .net micro framework which requires me to code for a pulse sensor. I have tried finding codes for pulse sensor but to no avail. I tried using AnalogInput codes for pulse sensor but the output values seemed wrong (there was a constant high value despite no heartbeat placed near the sensor). Please advise!

Here are my current codes for the heartbeat sensor:

```
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Sockets;
  using System.Threading;
  using Microsoft.SPOT;
  using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;
  using SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware;
  using SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware.Netduino;

  namespace heartrate
   {
   public class Program
  {
  public static void Main()
   {


    SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware.AnalogInput rate =
    new SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware.AnalogInput(Pins.GPIO_PIN_A0);
    int sensorvalue = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        sensorvalue = rate.Read();
        Debug.Print("" + sensorvalue);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
   }
 }
 }
```

Here are the specs of the sensor, how it looks like and how it is connected.
http://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=Pulse_Sensor
(This tutorial is for arduino, but I think the wiring is similar to that of Netduino)

Comment: This is unanswerable as your posted code essentially does nothing of importance, but merely invokes other mystery code. Nor have you provided any details about the specific wiring *of your attempt*. If you are following an Arduino tutorial, consider building and experimenting with that with an Arduino and only try to port it once you understand in detail how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without specs on your pulse device and how it is attached. For Analog input & output in my latest project (https://github.com/osstekz/cncBuddy) I use classes InputPort & OutputPort (Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware)
ex:

```
public NESControllerAdapter(Cpu.Pin pinClk, Cpu.Pin pinLatch, Cpu.Pin pinData1/*, Cpu.Pin pinData2 = Cpu.Pin.GPIO_NONE*/) {
        // Binds to all pins
        this._outpClk = new OutputPort(pinClk, false);
        this._outpLatch = new OutputPort(pinLatch, false);
        this._inpData1 = new InputPort(pinData1, false, Port.ResistorMode.Disabled);
        //if (pinData2 != Cpu.Pin.GPIO_NONE) this._inpData2 = new InputPort(pinData2, false, Port.ResistorMode.Disabled);
        }
```

...then like your rate.Read(); loop

```
public int ButtonPressed() {
    // Locks all parms
    this._PinTick(this._outpLatch);

    // Reads plug state value
    for (int i = 0; i < CncBuddyShared.iTOTALNESCONTROLLERBUTTONS; ++i) {
        // Read the value, if true return this index as the first pressed button
        if (this._inpData1.Read() == false) return i;

        // Selects the next value
        this._PinTick(this._outpClk);
        }
    return NESCONTROLLER_PRESSEDBUTTOM_NONE;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I've added a link that shows how I wired my sensor and how it looks like!